# RegularExpressionValidator always show error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, file-upload

Here is my code of `aspx`:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="ImageUpload" runat="server" Style="margin-bottom: 5px" />
<br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
 ErrorMessage="Only jpeg, png or gif files are allowed!"
 ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))
 +(.jpeg|.JPEG|.png|.PNG|.gif|.GIF)$" 
 ControlToValidate="ImageUpload"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I want to filter jpeg, png and gif file only in my `ImageUpload` .
But , when i upload jpeg,png and gif file , `RegularExpressionValidator` always show the Error Message .I want to know what's wrong in my code !

Comment: Are you trying to validate anything else with that regex or do you only want to assert that the extension is said image formats?

Comment: try add displaymode to dynamic

Comment: @rvalvik > It's image upload :) Just want to get image format only !

Comment: @wy__ , still doesn't work :|

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to assert the extension then you could try something like this:

```
\.(jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$
```

This would match anything that ends in a `.` followed by either of the above extensions.

**Edit:**

Without having tried it and having no experience with aspx, I think you should be able to use `(?i:)` to make it case insensitive:

```
(?i:\.jpeg|png|gif)$
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
            string extsn = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            if (extsn.ToUpper() == ".JPEG" || extsn.ToUpper() == ".PNG" || extsn.ToUpper() == ".GIF")
            { 

            }
        }
```